# Assign value of selected item from drop box to a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a select drop down whose values come from the database as shown below:

```
<aui:select id="empName" name="empName">
 <%
    List<Employee> EmpList =     EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.getEmployees(-1,-1);
for(Employee emp : EmpList ) {
  %>
  <aui:option value='<%=emp.getEmpFname()%>'><%=emp.getEmpFname()%><%=emp.getEmpLname()%></aui:option>
  <% } %>
</aui:select>
```

I assign this value to a label using the code below:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('select[id*=empName]').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();      
        $('#myUniqueLabelId').text(value);
     });
   });
```

where `myUniqueLabelId` is the id of the label.

I have radio buttons say-

```
 <input type = "radio" name = "radioex" id = "radio1 value = "ex1"/>
 <input type = "radio name = "radioex" id = "radio2"/>
```

to the radio button with `id = radio2` I want to assign the value selected from the drop box so that I can use it in my action class. How should I do this using **jQuery**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to assign the value of #radio2

```
$('select[id*=empName]').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();      
    $("#radio2").val(value);
});
```

Comment: Hey sorry for the prev comment. Well thanks for your prompt reply. I will accept your answer. It gives me the correct results.
I was using .text instead of .val hence it was showing me null values..